# Do I need to include space for the terminating char in my string array?

Tags: c, arrays

Apologies if I have some of the terminology wrong, I've been reading several pages and haven't seen an explicit answer to this and just want to make sure.

If I want to make a 10 character long array to build a string with, do I need to set its size to 10 or 11? I don't know what the word entered into the array is prior to compiling (as it comes from user input), just that it has a 10 character maximum. From what I've read there needs to be space for a \0 terminating char at the end of the array, so my question:

If I need to make a char [X} array that can hold at most 10 user inputted characters (e.g. a maximum word could be "applejacks"), will the size X be 10 or 11 for this array?

Comment: You need to reserve space for 11, as you say: 10 + 1 for the trailing `'\0'` (NUL)

Comment: Thank you so much, I know this seems really stupid I just wasn't sure and the site I was reading didn't outright say it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, when you are in doubt, ask the compiler: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof("applejacks"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends according to what your goal is:

Store an array of 10 `char`s:

```
char someChars[10];
```

Store a string of max. 10 `char`s:

```
char myString[11]; /* 10 + '\0' */
```

Please note that string it's not a C language type.

Comment: You're right @Keine Lust! I will change my reply according to that.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you need an extra byte for the mandatory <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte after the last character of any [C string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling). Remember that C strings don't really exist except as the *convention* of an array of non-<kbd>NUL</kbd> bytes (each of type `char`) terminated by one <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte, and many [string related functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) (such as `strlen` or `strchr`) expect that convention to hold. Also, a single displayed character on the screen could take more than one byte, depending on [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). The C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not *require* any particular encoding (however, its [§5.2.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1) imposes some constraints on the character set).

BTW, if (as you should, since in 2018 [**UTF-8 is everywhere**](http://utf8everywhere.org/)) you use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters, you could need 41 bytes in rare cases for 10 Unicode characters in UTF-8 (since some few Unicode characters -such as the  i.e. U+104D0 OSAGE CAPITAL LETTER KHA- need 4 bytes `\360\220\223\220` in UTF-8). For example my family name is in Russian spelled *Старынкевич* and that is 11 [cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) letters, but 22 bytes (+ 1 for the terminating <kbd>NUL</kbd>) in UTF-8.

At last, in practice, most strings are somehow [aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) (usually to the word), so it often -but not always- makes sense to use  `char` arrays of a multiple of four bytes.

Notice that the `char` keyword is confusing (for historical reasons, originally C used in the previous century some [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, and also had implementations using [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)); you need to think of it as a "byte" (and on some weird C implementations, it might even not have 8 bits), not as a displayable character glyph.

Today, you cannot expect (in professional software) every letter to be a Latin one. Read also about [Internationalization & Localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) of software.